How can we create a keycloak user which has access to one single client
Is it possible to configure realms in such a way that the users would be able to access admin UI(or security-console) only for the clients they have access to.
E.g. in a realm “test-realm”, there are three clients: “client1”, “client2”, and “client3”, respectively. I want some users to have access to the Admin UI only for client1, for example.
Admin for client1, would be able to add new roles, assign roles(belongs to client) to users etc.
Thanks

To achieve this in Keycloak, you need to configure client-specific roles and fine-grained admin permissions. This can be done by creating specific roles that are assigned only to certain clients and restricting the access of users to those clients accordingly.  Would you like more details?
